# App Launcher Icon Is Wrong

Tags: android, icons, app-launcher

The manifest defines the app icon that I want. But when I deploy the app the app icon is a completely different icon. What could possibly be going on?

The image that was showing as the icon is no where to be found in any of my project files. I haven't moved my ic_launcher images at all so they are all still in their appropriate drawable folder. It was showing fine an hour ago on another computer.

It started showing differently when I downloaded my code from an svn repository on another computer and started eclipse.

Cleaning my project fixed this.

Comment: Where is the icon stored and what is it's file name? Also, could you post a copy of the manifest, or at least the relevant part of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check paths (/res/drawable-*) and try to clean your project

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible, that your phone uses an other density than the icon you provided. Did you scale you icon down to all densities? Did you forget to delete the default app icon in the ldpi, mdpi and hdpi folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the res/drawable-hdpi,ldpi,mdpi have the correct images and sizes.

The website below might help you out with the sizes..
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html